# How to make default constructor private in base class?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, singleton, c++17

I want to have a class that make other class singleton when we inherit from it, so i wrote this:

```cpp
template <typename Class,
     typename T = std::enable_if<std::is_class_v<Class>>>
struct singleton
{
public:
    static Class* get_instance(void)
    {
        if (!object)
        {
            object = new Class;
        }
        return object;
    }

protected:
    static Class* object;
    singleton(void) = default;

private:
    singleton(const singleton&) = delete;
    singleton& operator=(const singleton&) = delete;
};
template <typename Class, typename T>
Class* singleton<Class, T>::object{nullptr};
```

And this's how i use it:

```cpp
struct some_base_class : public singleton<some_base_class>
{
private:
    size_t m_variable;

public:
    static auto make(const size_t var)
    {
        auto o{singleton<some_base_class>::get_instance()};
        o->m_variable = var;

        return o;
    }
};
```

But here `some_base_class` is not Singleton because in `singleton` class we make default constructor a protected member, i tried to make it a private member but i got this error:

```sh
use of deleted function ‘some_base_class::some_base_class()’
```

Why ? i just make it private member in base class and mark it `= default` not `= delete` !. How can i make default constructor private in base class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to make default constructor private in base class?

You can use the access specifier:

```
struct base {
private:  // this here
    base() = default;
```

> i got this error:
>
> ```
>  use of deleted function ‘some_base_class::some_base_class()’
> ```
>
> Why ?

Because you tried to default initialise the derived class.

And because the default constructor of a base is private, then the implicitly generated constructor of derived types are deleted. This is because there is no way to construct the base due to lack of access to the constructor.

Comment: So it's mean i can have a Singleton base class and use it to make other class singleton with inherited of that base class ?

Comment: @GhasemRamezani No, you cannot have such base class.

Answer (score 0):

looks like this error is referring to the parameterized constructor which you 
have marked delete...
use class instead of structure if you can because in default all members are private if you don't specify them public or protected...